Subset elements within categories of SpatRaster object
I have a SpatRaster object of crop cover taken from the USDA. This raster has five categories: RED, GREEN, BLUE, CLASS_NAME, and OPACITY. I am trying to subset a particular crop ("CORN" for example) within CLASS_NAME, but I am failing to do so.
I have included the output of the original SpatRaster below.
> usda
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 15133, 24345, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent      : 1204695, 1935045, 1829055, 2283045  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=aea +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs 
source      : CDL_2023_clip_20240401121659_1498934739.tif 
color table : 1 
categories  : RED, GREEN, BLUE, CLASS_NAME, OPACITY 
name        : RED 
min value   :  NA 
max value   :  NA 

I have tried to subset the data by using the terra::subset function.
I have tried:
usda_sub <- subset(usda, "RED")

but this gives me the same output as above with no change.
I have also tried other variations which give me errors:
> usda_sub <- subset(usda, "CLASS_NAME")
Error: [subset] invalid name(s)

> usda_sub <- subset(usda, "Corn")
Error: [subset] invalid name(s)

I understand how to subset the "name" element of a SpatRaster object, but clearly I do not know how to subset within other categories. For instance, subsetting "CORN" or "CRANBERRIES" within the CLASS_NAME category.

I am not sure how "subset" would apply to the cell-values of a raster (instead of the layers). I assume that you want to (re-) classify the values into "forest / not-forest" or "forest/NA". With these example data,
library(terra)
set.seed(0)
r <- rast(nrows=10, ncols=10)
values(r) <- sample(3, ncell(r), replace=TRUE)
cls <- data.frame(id=1:3, cover=c("forest", "water", "urban"))
levels(r) <- cls

you can distinguish the cells that are forest from all other cells like this,
forest1 <- r == "forest"

or like this:
forest2 <- subst(r, "forest", 1, others=NA)

For this to work with your data you need to set the active category to "CLASS_NAME" like this
activeCat(usda) <- "CLASS_NAME"

